# testing angular services: module is not defined

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-mock

I'm trying to include some tests on my example project and I downloaded the Jasmine standalone, pasted into my html files and then created the spec.html to call all sources and tests files. When I open my spec.html file to see the results on the browser, it didn't recognize the module() and inject() methods.

PS: I already included the angular-mocks.js

[image: methods]

[image: error on the browser]

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try `angular.mock.module()` instead of `module()`
2. Check that you don't need to include `angular-mocks.min.js` instead of  `angular-mocks.js`